# Create topographic map in R

Tags: r, maps, elevatr

I am trying to create a script that will generate a 2d topographic or contour map for a given set of coordinates. My goal is something similar to what is produced by

`contour(volcano)`

but for any location set by the user. This has proved surprisingly challenging! I have tried:

```
library(elevatr)
library(tidyr)

# Generate a data frame of lat/long coordinates.
ex.df <- data.frame(x=seq(from=-73, to=-71, length.out=10), 
                       y=seq(from=41, to=45, length.out=10))

# Specify projection.
prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

# Use elevatr package to get elevation data for each point.
df.sp <- get_elev_point(ex.df, prj = prj_dd, src = "epqs")

# Convert from spatial to regular data frame, remove extra column.
# Use tidyr to convert to lat x lon table with elevation as fill.
# Sorry for the terrible code, I know this is sloppy.
df <- as.data.frame(df.sp)
df$elev_units <- NULL
df.w <- df %>% spread(y, elevation)
df.w <- as.matrix(df.w)
```

This creates a matrix similar to the `volcano` dataset but filled with `NA`s except for the 10 lat/lon pairs with elevation data. `contour` can handle `NA`s, but the result of `contour(df.w)` has only a single tiny line on it. I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I simply need more points? Thanks in advance for any help--I'm pretty new to R and I think I've bitten off more than I can chew with this project.

Comment: Have you seen this post? [How to create a crisp topographical/terrain map with ggplot2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224035/how-to-create-a-crisp-topographical-terrain-map-with-ggplot2)

Comment: Yep, you need way more data. Make `ex.df` with something like `ex.df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-73, -71, length.out = 100), y = seq(41, 45, length.out = 100))`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for delay in responding.  I suppose I need to check SO for `elevatr` questions!

I would use `elevatr::get_elev_raster()`, which returns a raster object which can be plotted directly with `raster::contour()`.

Code example below grabs a smaller area and at a pretty coarse resolution. Resultant contour looks decent though.

```
library(elevatr)
library(raster)

# Generate a data frame of lat/long coordinates.
ex.df <- data.frame(x=seq(from=-73, to=-72.5, length.out=10), 
                    y=seq(from=41, to=41.5, length.out=10))

# Specify projection.
prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

# Use elevatr package to get elevation data for each point.
elev <- get_elev_raster(ex.df, prj = prj_dd, z = 10, clip = "bbox")

raster::contour(elev)
```

[image]

If it is a requirement to use `graphic::contour()`, you'll need to convert the raster object to a matrix first with `raster::as.matrix(elev)`.  That flips the coords though and I haven't spent enough time to try and get that part figured out...  Hopefully the `raster` solution works for you.