# show additional area around feature, get_elev_raster() (from elevatr)

Tags: r, maps, elevatr

Following the answer to this question ["Create topographic map in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834755/11549677) I would like to expand the bounding box to show additional area around the feature.  The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elevatr/elevatr.pdf) mentions the "expand" parameter but I'm not sure how it can be applied and my google searches have not returned code examples that I have been able to use successfully.

I am testing on a dataframe with just one set of coordinates at present ([Adam's peak, from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_Peak)), that looks like this:

[dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAH8b.png)

The code is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834755/11549677), as below, except for the first line "# Generate a data frame of lat/long coordinates"

```
library(elevatr)
library(raster)

#input dataframe
ex.df <- mtSlice

# Specify projection.
prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

# Use elevatr package to get elevation data for each point.
elev <- get_elev_raster(ex.df, prj = prj_dd, z = 10, clip = "bbox")

raster::contour(elev)
```

Would anyone be able to explain how to expand to show more area around the feature?

Answer (score 1):

The `expand` argument on `get_elev_raster` will expand the bounding box in the units of the CRS in your input locations.  In this case that will be decimal degrees. So, to get an additional 1 degree on your bounding box:

```r
elev_plus_one_deg <- get_elev_raster(ex.df, prj = prj_dd, z = 10, clip = "bbox", expand = 1)
```

note: It should be doing about an additional one degree, but on closer inspection it doesn't appear to be.  I need to dig into that!

Comment: Thanks @jhollist, do you mean it appears to be adding a different degree to the degree specified, or it does not appear to be adding a degree at all?

Comment: It does add to the area, just not an exact degree (in the case of decimal degrees as your unit).  The version on CRAN uses a buffer and buffers with non-projected/geographic data are not ideal.  In this case it will still give you a larger area, just not exactly one (or whatever value you choose) degree larger.  You'll need to experiment.

Comment: @WithRegards Just curious if you had your issue solved?  Any other questions?